# How to change the order of allocated QtObjects in Qt?

Tags: qt

I'm using QtCreator, and I created a GUI with LineEdit objects in a single widget. When I want to return a widget's objects, I call:

```
QList<QLineEdit *> boxes = ui->gridLayoutWidget->findChildren<QLineEdit *>();
```

Unfortunately, the order of those objects in the QList depends on the order they appear in the "ui" file. How could I go about changing the order?

For example, my ui file appears like this:

```
<layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
 <item row="5" column="8" alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter|Qt::AlignVCenter">
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="le_e7">
  </widget>
 </item>
 <item row="8" column="2" alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter|Qt::AlignVCenter">
  <widget class="QLineEdit" name="le_g3">
```

and so on. I have QLineEdit objects that follow a convention of "a1, a2, a3, etc." But they appear out of order like the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the QList, use [qSort](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtalgorithms.html#qSort-2) and provide your own *lessThan* function (functor or lambda) that will sort the list in the order you need.